# Is it possible to install gcloud (Google cloud sdk) on boot2docker?

Tags: docker, boot2docker, gcloud

I'm trying to follow the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/#linux) to install google cloud sdk on my boot2docker environment without success.

Is the boot2docker is a limited linux? what is missing?
The error I get is:

```
(23) Failed writing body
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the boot2docker is a limited linux?

Yes, [boot2docker](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker) is based on the [Tiny Core distro](http://tinycorelinux.net/), and has the following limitations:

- Only `C:\Users` or `/Users` is mounted
- symlinks are not supported.

If gcloud needs to access to another path or uses symlink, that would fail.

In general, boot2docker is there to host a docker dameon, and allows you to declare the installation of programs in *containers*.

See for example [`blacklabelops/gcloud`](https://github.com/blacklabelops/gcloud) which includes the latest Google Cloud SDK along with all modules (as [defined in its Dockerfile](https://github.com/blacklabelops/gcloud/blob/master/Dockerfile#L16-L20)).

**You would execute gcloud commands by running that container, not by installing gcloud directly on your boot2docker instance**.
For instance:

```
docker run -it --rm \
    -e "GCLOUD_ACCOUNT=$(base64 auth.json)" \
    -e "GCLOUD_ACCOUNT_EMAIL=useraccount@developer.gserviceaccount.com" \
    -e "CLOUDSDK_CORE_PROJECT=example-project" \
    -e "CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE=europe-west1-b" \
    -e "CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_REGION=europe-west1" \
    blacklabelops/gcloud \
    gcloud compute instances list
```